# Return same value for multiple exceptions

Tags: scala

Given a block that catches more than one exception is it possible to handle multiple exceptions without putting the desired value in every `case` block? e.g. it would be nice if something like this worked:

```
val foo: Int = try {
  //do stuff that results in an Int
} catch {
  case e: SomeException => //do something if this gets thrown
  case e: SomeOtherException => //do something different if this gets thrown
  0
}
```

But that results in a compile error (`type mismatch; found : Unit required: Int`). I could put the default in each throwable `case e: SomeException => {/*do something if this gets thrown*/; 0}` - but that just seems like code smell so I'm hoping there is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply wrap the exception handling:

```
val foo: Int = try {
  //do stuff that results in an Int
  17
} catch { case t: Throwable => t match {
    case e: SomeException => //do something if this gets thrown
    case e: SomeOtherException => //do something different if this gets thrown
  }
  42
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can take advantage of partial functions to do your error handling using the built in `Try`

```
 val foo: Int ={
   val value = Try{
     //stuff
   }
   unwrap(0, value){
     case x: SomeException => doStuff()
     case x: OtherExcetion => doMoreStuff()
   }
 }

 def unwrap[A](ret: A, value: Try[A])(f: Failure[A] => Unit): A = value match{
     case Success(x) => x
     case x: Failure => f(x); ret
   }
```

and voila, you've handled it quite well.

Answer (score 1):

The `catch` keyword expects a `PartialFunction`, which can easily be chained with `andThen`:

```
scala> val pf1: PartialFunction[Throwable, Unit] = { case _: IllegalArgumentException => println("pf1") }
pf1: PartialFunction[Throwable,Unit] = <function1>

scala> val pf2: PartialFunction[Unit, Int] = { case _ => println("pf2"); 0}
pf2: PartialFunction[Unit,Int] = <function1>

scala> try throw new IllegalArgumentException catch pf1 andThen pf2
pf1
pf2
res0: Int = 0

scala> try throw new NoSuchElementException catch pf1 andThen pf2
java.util.NoSuchElementException
```

The second `PartialFunction` is only executed when the first one matched its argument, which can be a problem when you want to catch other exceptions (that also should not return the default value). But for this case, there is `orElse`:

```
scala> val pf3: PartialFunction[Throwable, Int] = { case _ => println("pf3"); 1}
pf3: PartialFunction[Throwable,Int] = <function1>

scala> try throw new NoSuchElementException catch pf1 andThen pf2 orElse pf3
pf3
res2: Int = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Try](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.util.Try) object to wrap your possibly failing code, and then compose the outcome like this

```
val foo: Int = (Try {
  //do stuff that results in an Int
} recover {
  //here we handle the recovering
  handleFail andThen defaultInt
}).get

val handleFail: PartialFunction[Throwable, Unit] = {
  case e: SomeException => //do something if this gets thrown
  case e: SomeOtherException => //do something different if this gets thrown

val defaultInt: PartialFunction[Unit, Int] = { case _ => 0 }
```